# Why Sping Boot native query return null?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to return a list in jsp from jsp:useBean and I tried the query working in mysql database. Somehow this query always return null and throw an exception on eclipse and it won't stop at break points:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM customize_service WHERE account_id=:acctid AND biz_id=:bizid and active=:active",
            nativeQuery=true)
public List<Service> getServices(@Param("acctid") String acctid, @Param("bizid") String bizid, @Param("active") int active);
```

Stuck, hope someone can help!

Newbie

Comment: Please add your NPE that you're getting. Query seems fine

Comment: Check your input parameters. NPE might indicate that you pass `null` as `@Param("active")`. Null can't be converted to primitive type (int). Probable solution is to change `active`'s type to `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

Native query returns object only

use this one:

```
public List<Object> getServices(@Param("acctid") String acctid, @Param("bizid") String bizid, @Param("active") int active);
```

Comment: I guess it should be `List<Object[]>`

Comment: Neither, both still throw null pointer exception. @Nikolai Shevchenko